# Recursive model design

Tags: mvvm, model, mvp

The software I am working on uses an API which roughly has this organization : (you might have to read it two times in order to resolve the symbols :) )

- A scenario is a process which contains a set of intervals (duration) and events (time point).
- An interval is defined by its beginning and end events, which specifies the time at which it starts and ends (hence its duration). An interval can hold an arbitrary number of processes (like a scenario).
- An event is just a point in time.

Events can be placed on a graphical view in order to create a scenario.

As you can see, this model is recursive, since you can put a scenario in an interval, and another interval inside this scenario *ad infinitum*.

My question is : in a "view model" - "presenter" - "view" pattern, what should be the ownership relations of the API objects and the view model objects ? Should I let the API manage the ownership of its own model objects, like Event & Interval, or should I instantiate them when I instantiate the corresponding view model objects ? Is there a best practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably let the API manage its own domain objects, and in your project map those objects to custom Model or ViewModel objects as necessary

Whenever working with ViewModels, try to remember that MVVM or MVP is a pattern for your UI, not a pattern for business logic.  Presenters should call other classes (which should be regarded as outside the MVVM/MVP/MVPVM pattern) to do their business logic.  It sounds like the API you mention provides a lot of your business functionality; ideally, your models would be specific to your app and then you would map the API's objects to your model objects appropriately.

It is common and sometimes a mistake to use the domain objects (e.g. those provided by the API) as your Model, so be careful, for the instant that you need a property or attribute on your Model that isn't provided by the API object, you are stuck and confused.  Be very willing to map the API's objects to your custom Model objects that exist only for your app or site.

When in doubt, get back to [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29), especially the single-responsibility principle.

Hope I understood you rightly.

Comment: Two months ago I was not so sure, but I followed this track and the software is going on a good way :)

Comment: Very glad to hear it.